# Can I fast travel when I would be over-encumbered except not because of a temporary effect?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am playing Skyrim and I have made some fortify carry weight potions. If I am carrying too much and drink a [fortify carry weight](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Fortify_Carry_Weight) potion, can I fast travel since this is only a temporary effect.

Comment: What happens when you try?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Yes,** drinking a potion that fortifies your carry weight *will* allow you to fast travel, provided that you do so before the effect expires and the potion's effect is strong enough such that while under its effect you are no longer over-encumbered. I've done this myself numerous times.

Comment: Worth noting: even if you drink the carry weight potion and immediately fast travel the potion will expire on arrival. So traveling somewhere with a shop or storage is suggested.

Answer (score 6):

A fortify carry weight potion enables fast travel for any distance (as long as the potion's effect gets you beyond the level of being encumbered). The distance/time covered by the travel can be arbitrarily long, even longer than the potion's duration.

Answer (score 0):

Drinking a potion works fine, however if you have a horse, or are able to summon the horse Arvak (Dawnguard DLC) you can fast travel while riding. Also it is possible to do so while riding a Dragon (Dragonborn DLC).

Saves time on finding or making potions, and lets you make more money off of the ones that you would find.